# stop the AVAudioPlayer on viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am working on an app in Xcode which uses AVAudioPlayer.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

on tap of an image I call a function which plays the audio file:

```
-(void)playMusic{
        if(self.player.currentTime == 0.0){
            self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sound.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]] error:nil];
            self.player.numberOfLoops = 0;
            [self.player play];
        }
}
```

on viewWillDisappear I need to stop the player, so I call:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.player stop];
}
```

But the above code does not work, and the audio does not stop playing.

Can anyone please tell me what the issue could be ?

Comment: Have you tried calling *[self.player pause];* ?

Comment: Also you should be using *_player* rather than *self.player*

Comment: I tried [self.player pause]; but it does not work. I also tried [_player pause];

Comment: did u check whether viewWillDisappear get called

Comment: yes it gets called, I tried using NSLog

Comment: yes play works properly

Comment: For checking purpose have ur stop method inside button action and try

Comment: Your code appears correct.  If your positive viewWillDisappear gets called, have you tried to put a break point on that line to confirm 'self.player' still points where it should?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: check if playMusic get called after viewWillDisappear?

Comment: You don't have to write "self.",  and also you must set delegate. Use this player.delegate=self.  It should help you. And also write AVAudioPlayerDelegate to your header.

Comment: playMusic gets called on tap of image. Not after viewWillDisappear

Comment: I tried adding AVAudioPlayerDelegate to the header, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you stop Playing song with same image tap as,

```
   if([player isPlaying] )
    {
        [player pause];
    }
    else
    [player play];
```

Comment: but I don't wan the player to stop on tap of the image. I want it to stop when the view changes.